# How to design this spark join

Tags: join, apache-spark, rdd

I need to join two big RDDs and potentially twice. Any help is appreciated to design these joins.

- Here is the problem,
- First RDD is `productIdA, productIdB, similarity` and the size is about 100G.
- Second RDD is `customerId, productId, boughtPrice` and size is about 35G.
- The result RDD I want is `productIdA, productIdB, similarity, customerIds bought both product A and B`.
- Because I cannot broadcast either of the RDD since both of them are quite big, my design is to aggregate the second RDD by `product id` then join the first RDD `twice` but I get huge shuffle spill and all kinds of errors (OOM or out of space because of shuffle). Put the errors aside, I would like to know if any better way to achieve the same result. Thanks

Comment: How is `similarity` computed?

Comment: What exactly you want to receive? What search criteria will you have? The join plan depends on what you are searching for and how much results you will like to fetch. Sometimes it is more productive to have a temporary table and so on.  Give us much details you can. Is it a once time query or a regular one? Huge data queries are very specific. Help us as much you can.

Comment: @zero323 The similarity is calculated by other component using product features like price, vender etc.

Comment: @mita so the first rdd is like a content based similarity matrix of products which is calculated by other team. And the second rdd is customer transactions. This job is not a query but a batch job to apply weighting on the similarity score by using the customer interactions. Hope that makes it clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a row for every product pairing in the first RDD?

If you do (or it's close), then you might want to do something like group the second RDD by `customerId`, create an element for every pairing, then rearrange and group that RDD by pairing, then group to get a list of `customerId`s, then join to add in the `similarity`.

(Whether or not this will result in more or less math depends, I think, on the distribution of number of products purchased per customer.)

Like zero323's comment also implies, once you have the pairings from grouping on `customerId`, it might be cheaper to recalculate the `similarity` than to join on a huge dataset.

Comment: I would add that when you already have actual pairs you can filter first RDD in roughly O(N)  to make eventual join significantly cheaper.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Zero323. Like the comment I just added, the sim score is calculated by other component, here I use customer transactions to apply weightings on these sim scores.

Comment: I will give your method a try.